# Unexpected change of column name to V1

Tags: r

When running my code I have 2 issues when executing the code after the line "View(df)".

Firstly, I try to delete the first two empty rows, but instead everything gets deleted.
EDIT: The selection of the first 2 rows needs to be done with regex. Anything which looks empty should be deleted (An unknown number of spaces or line breaks).

Secondly, the column name is changing unexpectedly to V1. (This is also happening when running the last line of the code without the previous "regex line"). Surprisingly, this issue does not occur when I do not delete the column "a" first.

EDIT: a screen shot after performing the code without the second to last line of code.

[image: column name is changing unexpectedly to V1]

Any help is much appreciated!

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a=c(1:8), b=c(" ", " ","tomato", "apple", "orange 1", "peach", "lemon", "orange 2"))
df <- dplyr::select(df, -c(a))
df <- df %>% rename(fruit = b)
View(df)

df <- df[grepl("[[:alnum:]]", df$fruit), ]
df <- df[-1, ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regex and select rows with any alphabetic characters, we can do

```
subset(df, grepl('[A-Za-z]', friut))

#     friut
#3   tomato
#4    apple
#5 orange 1
#6    peach
#7    lemon
#8 orange 2
```

Or similarly,

```
subset(df, grepl('[:alpha:]', friut))
```

Looking at the data, selecting non-empty rows also seem to work.

```
subset(df, friut != ' ')
```

Comment: Thank you, I found out that numbers in the regex make some trouble for some reason (i.e. < df <- subset(df, grepl('[A-z0-9]', fruit)) does not work >) . subset(df, grepl('[:alpha:]', friut)) does not work therefore somehow. Note that subset(df, friut != ' ') is not flexible enough for me unfortunately. But the second question remains, even with this workaround. Why do I get a transformation of the variable name if I do df <- df[-1, ] ?

Comment: @stefan485 What is the pattern that you are looking for? On what basis do you want to select rows ? I am not able to reproduce the transformation of variable name.

Comment: anything which looks empty should be deleted (An unknown number of spaces or line breaks).

Comment: @stefan485 So do you mean something like this ? `subset(df, grepl('[A-Za-z]|[0-9]', friut))`

Comment: Yes, this guy works for some reason! Thank you! But Still getting the V1 error. The selection and deleting of rows this way (i.e df <- df[-1, ]) is documented in base R, so what the heck? This issue does not occur if I have more than one variable.

Comment: @stefan485 Yes, I see. In that case you need to add `drop = FALSE`. Try `df[-1, , drop = FALSE]` because when we subset dataframe with only one column it by default does that. More information in `?Extract`.

Comment: Thank you, this is it!!